ESP32C3 - UART flashing issue (restarting? - loop)
I am struggling with ESP32-C3-mini-1 flashing issue.
According to datasheet power-up sequence for boot uart flashing looks correct:

IO8 - high, IO9 low, IO2 - high (not necessary)
Delay 10 ms
PWR-UP 3.3V
Enable pulled to 3.3V via 10k resistor with 100nF delay capacitor.

Anyway I am not able to flash chip. Instead I obtained some loop in log:
[19:05:50:673] ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207␍␊
[19:05:50:673] Build:Feb  7 2021␍␊
[19:05:50:673] rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0x5 (DOWNLOAD(USB/UART0/1))␍␊
[19:05:50:673] Saved PC:0x40048b82␍␊
[19:05:50:718] Download boot modes disabled␍␊
[19:05:50:718] ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207␍␊
[19:05:50:718] Build:Feb  7 2021␍␊
[19:05:50:718] rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0x5 (DOWNLOAD(USB/UART0/1))␍␊
[19:05:50:718] Saved PC:0x40048b82␍␊
[19:05:50:718] Download boot modes disabled␍␊

Power supply 3.3V looks clear without any glitches.
Any ideas what can be wrong or what can be checked?
Thank you.
